# Routing table in QNX

Tags: routing

I've an embedded system running on QNX 6.2.1.  (I'll call it QNX box.) The QNX box has two network adaptors. I've configured the driver, so they appear as en0 and en1. Here are their IP settings:

```
en0: IP address 10.0.0.2, subnetmask 255.255.240.0 
en1: IP address 10.1.0.3, subnetmask 255.255.240.0
```

The en0 and en1 are connected to different PCs with IP address 10.0.0.1 and 10.1.0.4 respectively. I can ping en0 and en1 from the connected PCs. No problem.

Now I want to ping one PC from the other PC, so the traffic must pass through the QNX box. The QNX box must have a routing table.

Can anyone suggest how I should do this?

I've tried

```
route add 10.0.0.1 -interface 10.0.0.2
route add 10.1.0.4 -interface 10.1.0.4
```

... doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

I've added

```
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

the output is

```
net.inet.ip.forwarding: 0 -> 1
```

The output for `netstat -r` is

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Refs     Use    Mtu  Interface
default            link#2             UCS         0        0   1500  en0
10/20              link#2             UC          1        0   1500  en0
10.0.0.1           00:17:3f:cf:03:95  UHL         7      130   1500  en0
10.1/20            link#3             UC          1        0   1500  en1
10.1.0.4           2c:27:d7:26:fd:91  UHL         0        4   1500  en1
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH          0        0  33212  lo0
```

Comment: Does the 10.0.0.1 host have default route or 10.1/20 route towards 10.0.0.2 (and similarly for the 10.1.0.4)?

Comment: I don't understand. I think, looking at routing table, link#2 is the default (to host 10.0.0.1).

Comment: When 10.0.0.1 tries to ping 10.1.0.4 10.0.0.1 needs to have route for 10.1.0.4 pointing to the QNX (10.0.0.2). I'm guessing your QNX is now good to go, your hosts are just missing routes.

Comment: I see, you mean I need a routing table on host 10.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes your 10.0.0.1 and 10.1.0.4 host MUST know how to send packets to each other. The QNX is ready to route/forward the packets now, but the hosts are not sending it anything as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documents](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/utilities/s/sysctl.html) you need explicitly enable IP forwarding:

> net.inet.ip.forwarding
>   Disable (0) or enable (1) IP forwarding. If this is enabled, the host acts as a router.

That would be 'sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1'

I don't have QNX to test, but I don't think you need to add any routes, as the connected interfaces already have network, i.e. route already exists.

But confirm with 'netstat -r'

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: Could you add in your question the output of 'netstat -r' and the output of 'sysctl  net.inet.ip.forwarding'